# REGEX - Parse JavaScript variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to parse the contents of a Javascript within an HTML page but, rather unsuccessfully.

Specifically, I'm trying to find the contents of a `var myData = 'my content';` ignoring everything else.

The problem seems to boil down to three parts:

- First non-capturing group defines the string should start with `var myData = '`, meaning, `(?:^var myData=')`
- The second non-capturing group defines how the string should end: `';`, and it should somehow only count the first time to get the variable's enclosing? (since there may be multiple cases of `';` on a web page/ javascript), something like `?(?:';$)$`
- Then we have the first and only capturing group which is everything between the first and second non-capturing groups, which corresponds to `(.*)`

All together becomes: `(?:^var myData= ')(.*)?(?:';$)$` but unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: Maybe try replacing `.` with `([^']|\\')+` so you specifically don't allow single quotes inside the string.

Comment: You are not matching the space between `myData` and the `=` You can write the pattern as `^var myData = '([^']*)';`

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird, it helps, so does @Louys Patrice Bessette's answer. But its still not working for complex cases like `<div> var myData = 'asdas'; </div` or `<div> var myData = 'asdas'; </div> <script> var someVar = 1;</script>`

Answer (score -1):

The possible spaces around the equal sign looks to be your issue. Add some `\s?`

Then, possibly there are double quotes instead of singles, so use `['"]`.

```
(?:^var myData\s?=\s?['"])(.*)?(?:['"];$)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Whilst your changes are spot-on, they still miss a part of the requirements: what if the REGEX is inside other text? `<div> var myData = 'asdas'; </div>` or
`<div> var myData = 'asdas'; </div> <script> var someVar = 1;</script>`, I guess `(?:.*)(?:^var myData\s?=\s?['"])(.*)?(?:['"];$)?(.*)` could work, but it doesn't

Comment: To get matches in the middle of a string, just remove the `^` and `$`, which are specifies the begin and end of a line. -- For the integer case and any other ones you can think of... You certainly will need to use some additional separate regexes. -- Try yourself on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and check the detailled aexplanations in the right side bar. ;)